# Display price based on User selection

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I can't seem to get the price to display on the page with image. The correct image displays and the correct price is passed to PayPal, but I can't get price based on the selection to display with the image.

```js
   
$(function() {
    $('.payment_form').change(function() {
        var filename = $('#dlist').val() + '-' + $('#os1').val() + '.png';
        console.log(filename);
        $('#imgToChange').prop('src', filename);
    });
});
</script>

<script language=javascript>

 function getOption(select, dataAttr) {
  const option = select.options[select.selectedIndex];
  if (option) {
    return option.getAttribute(dataAttr);
  }
  return '';
}

function CalculateOrder() {
  const form = document.getElementById('payment_form');
  const os0 = document.getElementById('os0');
  const os1 = document.getElementById('os1');
  const os2 = document.getElementById('os2');
  const os3 = document.getElementById('os3');

  let price = parseFloat(getOption(os1, 'data-base-price'));

  if (os0.value == "2XL") {
    price = price + 1;
  } else if (os0.value == "3XL") {
    price = price + 2;
  } else if (os0.value == "4XL") {
    price = price + 3;
  } else if (os0.value == "5XL") {
    price = price + 4;
  }

  form.amount.value = price;
}

CalculateOrder()

function showTest(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  const form = document.getElementById('payment_form');
  console.log('price: ' + form.amount.value)
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.min.js"
integrity="sha256-9/aliU8dGd2tb6OSsuzixeV4y/faTqgFtohetphbbj0=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>


<form target="_self" action="https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post" id="payment_form" onchange="CalculateOrder()">
  <div align="center">
    <h2>Make selection below:<br />
      <br />
    </h2>
    <p>
      <input type="hidden" name="on0" value="Design"> 
      Design:&nbsp;&nbsp;
      <select name="os0" id="dlist" class="payment_form">
        <option value="Designer1">Designer1</option>
        <option value="Designer2">Designer2</option>
        <option value="Designer3">Designer3</option>
      </select>
      <br><br>
      <input type="hidden" name="on1" value="Style"> Style:&nbsp;&nbsp;
      <select name="os1" id="os1" class="payment_form">
        <option value="Tshirt" data-base-price="10">T-shirt</option>
        <option value="LSleeve" data-base-price="15">L Sleeve</option>
        <option value="Sweater" data-base-price="20">Sweater</option>
      </select>
      <br><br>
      <input type="hidden" name="on2" value="Size"> Size:&nbsp;&nbsp;
      <SELECT name="os2" id="os0">
        <OPTION value="S" data-item-number="Small">S</OPTION>
        <OPTION value="M" data-item-number="W-T-Medium">M</OPTION>
        <OPTION value="LG" data-item-number="W-T-LG">LG</OPTION>
        <OPTION value="XL" data-item-number="W-T-XL">XL</OPTION>
        <OPTION value="2XL" data-item-number="W-T-2XL">2XL</OPTION>
        <OPTION value="3XL" data-item-number="W-T-3XL">3XL</OPTION>
        <OPTION value="4XL" data-item-number="W-T-4XL">4XL</OPTION>
        <OPTION value="5XL" data-item-number="W-T-5XL">5XL</OPTION>
      </SELECT>
      <br><br>
      <input type="hidden" name="on3" value="Color"> Color:&nbsp;&nbsp;
      <select name="os3">
        <option value="Gray">Gray</option>
        <option value="White">White</option>
      </select>
      
      <input type="hidden" name="add" value="1">
      <input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_cart">
      <input type="hidden" name="business" value="abc.com">
      <input type="hidden" name="item_name" value="Shirts">
      <input type="hidden" name="amount">
      <input type="hidden" name="item_number">
      <input type="hidden" name="no_shipping" value="2">
      <input type="hidden" name="shipping">
      <img alt="" border="0" src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/en_US/i/scr/pixel.gif" width="1" height="1">
      <input type="hidden" name="shopping_url" value="http://example.com/store.html">
      <input type="hidden" name="return" value="http://www.example.com/">
      <input type="hidden" name="currency_code" value="USD">
      <input type="hidden" name="lc" value="US">
      <input type="hidden" name="bn" value="PP-ShopCartBF">
      
      </p>
  </p>
    <p>      <INPUT onclick=CalculateOrder(this.form) type=image alt="Make payments with PayPal - it's fast, free and secure!" src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/en_US/i/btn/btn_cart_LG.gif" border=0 name="submit">
  </p>
  </div>
</FORM>
```

I can not seem to get the price to display on the page with image. The correct image displays and the correct price is passed to PayPal, but I can't get price based on the selection to display with the image.

Comment: Don't put the script tag in the javascript section of a snippet.  Also add a JQuery tag at the beginning of the html so we can test your code.

Comment: You can't do `os0.value` to get the value of a `select` tag.  You could do `$('#os0').prop('value')`.

Comment: You guys make this stuff looks so easy... I actually wanted it to start at the base price for each of $10. On your demo I see that it starts with $0 displayed but on my page it doesn't appear until I make a selection. Is that because I missed a step... Want it have $10 as soon as the page is loaded even before a selection is made.

Comment: @BBlyden you need to the copy the `exact` HTML and jQuery i have provided in my answer - Please.

Comment: I will keep working at it....copied exactly what you have and it still won't start with the price displayed until I make a selection..

Comment: @BBlyden It works perfectly in my answer snippet below. As soon as you run snippet it shows "Price: 10" - i high doubt that you did not copy my answer and using some of your own code.

Comment: I do agree its working in your snippet.. Not doubting your expertise. I even copied the exact script and pasted it into a new page just for testing and still get the same results. Its strange but will call it a night and try again.

Comment: @BBlyden Sure. Let me know how you go. or if i can help further.

Comment: I feel so stupid... So after moving the javascript after the form, it worked like it should. So much to learn here. Thanks for all the assistance.

Comment: I have Deleted this answer since you choose the other answer. even thought my answer with was much better approach which uses Id and class selector. You will have issue if you have other amount Input on your page. Any ways good luck.

Comment: I did use your solution...I must have selected the wrong one...I am very new to this so please forgive me.

Comment: @BBlyden you selected the other answer again. You can only check mark in **one** answer not both of them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The price is stored in $("input[name='amount']" ).val()

You put the function CalculateOrder() in the JQuery .change().
So, when a select in changing, it calculate the new price.

And you apply the class "payment_form" to all the < select > you want that trigger the calculation.

King regards.

*_Teddy_*

```js
$(function() {
    $('.payment_form').change(function() {
// ***************************
CalculateOrder()
// ***************************
        var filename = $('#dlist').val() + '-' + $('#os1').val() + '.png';
        console.log(filename);
        $('#imgToChange').prop('src', filename);
// ***************************
$('#priceP').html('Price : $ '+$("input[name='amount']" ).val());
// ***************************

    });
});
</script>

<script language=javascript>


function swapImage(){
   var image = document.getElementById("imageToSwap");
   var dropd = document.getElementById("dlist");
   image.src = dropd.value;   
};

 function getOption(select, dataAttr) {
  const option = select.options[select.selectedIndex];
  if (option) {
    return option.getAttribute(dataAttr);
  }
  return '';
}

function CalculateOrder() {
  const form = document.getElementById('payment_form');
  const os0 = document.getElementById('os0');
  const os1 = document.getElementById('os1');
  const os2 = document.getElementById('os2');
  const os3 = document.getElementById('os3');

  let price = parseFloat(getOption(os1, 'data-base-price'));

  if (os0.value == "2XL") {
    price = price + 1;
  } else if (os0.value == "3XL") {
    price = price + 2;
  } else if (os0.value == "4XL") {
    price = price + 3;
  } else if (os0.value == "5XL") {
    price = price + 4;
  }

  form.amount.value = price;
}

CalculateOrder()

function showTest(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  const form = document.getElementById('payment_form');
  console.log('price: ' + form.amount.value)
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.min.js"
integrity="sha256-9/aliU8dGd2tb6OSsuzixeV4y/faTqgFtohetphbbj0=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>


<form target="_self" action="https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post" id="payment_form" onchange="CalculateOrder()">
  <div align="center">
    <h2>Make selection below:<br />
      <br />
    </h2>
    <p>
      <input type="hidden" name="on0" value="Design"> 
      Design:&nbsp;&nbsp;
      <select name="os0" id="dlist" class="payment_form">
        <option value="Designer1">Designer1</option>
        <option value="Designer2">Designer2</option>
        <option value="Designer3">Designer3</option>
      </select>
      <br><br>
      <input type="hidden" name="on1" value="Style"> Style:&nbsp;&nbsp;
      <select name="os1" id="os1" class="payment_form">
        <option value="Tshirt" data-base-price="10">T-shirt</option>
        <option value="LSleeve" data-base-price="15">L Sleeve</option>
        <option value="Sweater" data-base-price="20">Sweater</option>
      </select>
      <br><br>
      <input type="hidden" name="on2" value="Size"> Size:&nbsp;&nbsp;
<!-- *************************** -->
<SELECT name="os2" id="os0" class="payment_form">
<!-- *************************** -->
<OPTION value="S" data-item-number="Small">S</OPTION>
        <OPTION value="M" data-item-number="W-T-Medium">M</OPTION>
        <OPTION value="LG" data-item-number="W-T-LG">LG</OPTION>
        <OPTION value="XL" data-item-number="W-T-XL">XL</OPTION>
        <OPTION value="2XL" data-item-number="W-T-2XL">2XL</OPTION>
        <OPTION value="3XL" data-item-number="W-T-3XL">3XL</OPTION>
        <OPTION value="4XL" data-item-number="W-T-4XL">4XL</OPTION>
        <OPTION value="5XL" data-item-number="W-T-5XL">5XL</OPTION>
      </SELECT>
      <br><br>
      <input type="hidden" name="on3" value="Color"> Color:&nbsp;&nbsp;
<!-- *************************** -->
      <select name="os3" class="payment_form">
<!-- *************************** -->
        <option value="Gray">Gray</option>
        <option value="White">White</option>
      </select>
      
      <input type="hidden" name="add" value="1">
      <input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_cart">
      <input type="hidden" name="business" value="abc.com">
      <input type="hidden" name="item_name" value="Shirts">
      <input type="hidden" name="amount">
      <input type="hidden" name="item_number">
      <input type="hidden" name="no_shipping" value="2">
      <input type="hidden" name="shipping">
      <img alt="" border="0" src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/en_US/i/scr/pixel.gif" width="1" height="1">
      <input type="hidden" name="shopping_url" value="http://example.com/store.html">
      <input type="hidden" name="return" value="http://www.example.com/">
      <input type="hidden" name="currency_code" value="USD">
      <input type="hidden" name="lc" value="US">
      <input type="hidden" name="bn" value="PP-ShopCartBF">
      
      </p>
  </p>
<!-- *************************** -->
<p id="priceP">$&nbsp;10</p>
<!-- *************************** -->
    <p>      <INPUT onclick=CalculateOrder(this.form) type=image alt="Make payments with PayPal - it's fast, free and secure!" src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/en_US/i/btn/btn_cart_LG.gif" border=0 name="submit">
  </p>
  </div>
</FORM>
```

Comment: Thanks you sir... It seems like price only appears when I make a change in the style. The price should also change based on the size. Also, how do I make the based price appear prior to the user selection?

Comment: I complete my answer.

Comment: @EddyMERCIER We do not need to call `CalculateOrder()` like five time. You can simply put the price in `CalculateOrder()` function and thats it. - See my answer

Comment: @AlwaysHelping But I think BBlyden wants the new price to appear when the user changes the selections. So you need th re-calculate it on each .change(). See my' edit' for the default price to $10.

Answer (score 2):

Initially the `price` is set to `zero` and will be `visible` on the page `prior` to any user selection.

As soon you change the `style` OR `size` the `price` will update as well. We need to update `price` in the `CalculateOrder()` function to show the updated price.

**Live Demo:**

```js
$(function() {
  $('.price').html('Price: ' + 10) //set the to $10 first
  $('.payment_form').change(function() {
    var filename = $('#dlist').val() + '-' + $('#os1').val() + '.png';
    //console.log(filename);
    $('#imgToChange').prop('src', filename);
  });
});

function getOption(select, dataAttr) {
  const option = select.options[select.selectedIndex];
  if (option) {
    return option.getAttribute(dataAttr);
  }
  return '';
}

function CalculateOrder() {
  const form = document.getElementById('payment_form');
  const os0 = document.getElementById('os0');
  const os1 = document.getElementById('os1');
  const os2 = document.getElementById('os2');
  const os3 = document.getElementById('os3');
  let price = parseFloat(getOption(os1, 'data-base-price'));
  if (os0.value == "2XL") {
    price = price + 1;
  } else if (os0.value == "3XL") {
    price = price + 2;
  } else if (os0.value == "4XL") {
    price = price + 3;
  } else if (os0.value == "5XL") {
    price = price + 4;
  }

  //Show price
  $('.price').html('Price: ' + price) //change price
  form.amount.value = price;
}

CalculateOrder()
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form target="_self" action="https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post" id="payment_form" onchange="CalculateOrder()">
  <div align="center">
    <h2>Make selection below:<br />
      <br />
    </h2>
    <p>
      <input type="hidden" name="on0" value="Design">
      Design:&nbsp;&nbsp;
      <select name="os0" id="dlist" class="payment_form">
        <option value="Designer1">Designer1</option>
        <option value="Designer2">Designer2</option>
        <option value="Designer3">Designer3</option>
      </select>
      <br><br>
      <input type="hidden" name="on1" value="Style"> Style:&nbsp;&nbsp;
      <select name="os1" id="os1" class="payment_form">
        <option value="Tshirt" data-base-price="10">T-shirt</option>
        <option value="LSleeve" data-base-price="15">L Sleeve</option>
        <option value="Sweater" data-base-price="20">Sweater</option>
      </select>
      <br><br>
      <input type="hidden" name="on2" value="Size"> Size:&nbsp;&nbsp;
      <SELECT name="os2" id="os0">
        <OPTION value="S" data-item-number="Small">S</OPTION>
        <OPTION value="M" data-item-number="W-T-Medium">M</OPTION>
        <OPTION value="LG" data-item-number="W-T-LG">LG</OPTION>
        <OPTION value="XL" data-item-number="W-T-XL">XL</OPTION>
        <OPTION value="2XL" data-item-number="W-T-2XL">2XL</OPTION>
        <OPTION value="3XL" data-item-number="W-T-3XL">3XL</OPTION>
        <OPTION value="4XL" data-item-number="W-T-4XL">4XL</OPTION>
        <OPTION value="5XL" data-item-number="W-T-5XL">5XL</OPTION>
      </SELECT>
      <br><br>
      <input type="hidden" name="on3" value="Color"> Color:&nbsp;&nbsp;
      <select name="os3">
        <option value="Gray">Gray</option>
        <option value="White">White</option>
      </select>

      <input type="hidden" name="add" value="1">
      <input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_cart">
      <input type="hidden" name="business" value="abc.com">
      <input type="hidden" name="item_name" value="Shirts">
      <input type="hidden" id="final_amount" name="amount">
      <input type="hidden" name="item_number">
      <input type="hidden" name="no_shipping" value="2">
      <input type="hidden" name="shipping">
      <img alt="" border="0" src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/en_US/i/scr/pixel.gif" width="1" height="1">
      <input type="hidden" name="shopping_url" value="http://example.com/store.html">
      <input type="hidden" name="return" value="http://www.example.com/">
      <input type="hidden" name="currency_code" value="USD">
      <input type="hidden" name="lc" value="US">
      <input type="hidden" name="bn" value="PP-ShopCartBF">

    </p>
    </p>
    <span class="price"></span>
    <p> <INPUT onclick=CalculateOrder(this.form) type=image alt="Make payments with PayPal - it's fast, free and secure!" src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/en_US/i/btn/btn_cart_LG.gif" border=0 name="submit">
    </p>
  </div>
</form>
```